# How to re-use socket connections?

Tags: java, android, ssl, httpurlconnection, serversocket

I have a Client Server Application wherein my client (multiple mobile devices) use HttpsURLConnection to connect to the Server IP/Port. It is a simple application wherein a customer walks-in to the store, makes a transaction on the Teller Mobile Device and leaves. What I want is not to re-establish the expensive SSL handshake every time. I read through a lot of documentation which suggests which we should use close() and then disconnect(). They also talk about sockets being re-used even after close() and disconnect() is called from a pool. 
My requirement is simple:
1. I want to make connection to server
2. Send Req and get Resp
3. Close()/Disconnect() only if necessary
4. Then re-send Req/Resp for another customer.

If sockets are being cached and re-used from the pool, is there a possibility that some client device may get an error saying No More Sockets available for connection?

Basically I want to re-use socket connections but at the same time do not want some device to get an error on No Socket available on Server.

Please suggest the best approach for this.

Comment: Mine is different? Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Suppose *you* 'elaborate more' on how your question is different?